# Iframe video from Angular Array using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iframe

I'm having some trouble getting an iframe to work through using ng-bind-html. I have all my data inside an array. I've been mainly using ng-bind-html to keep it all in one place. I can't seem to get it to work with iframe's though.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. 
`x`[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R0t7g4qBdinMWBNVoXBT?p=info)

As you can see it isn't really doing anything.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in the question and specifically ask about what you're expecting to happen and what's not working.

Comment: Did you gave my solution a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$sce`:

> $sce [("Strict Contextual Escaping")](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) is a built-in angular service that automatically sanitize content and internal sources in templates.

injecting **external** sources and **raw HTML**  into the template requires manual wrapping of`$sce`.

**In this example we'll create a simple $sce sanitation filter:**.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9tpXY7RF3QWN4eIXPdEU?p=preview)

```
.filter('sanitizer', ['$sce', [function($sce) {
     return function(content) {
          return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(content);
      };
}]);
```

**Usage in template**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    
    <!-- Sanitize external sources -->
    <iframe ng-src="{{item.youtube_url | sanitizer}}">
    
    <!-- Sanitaize and render HTML -->
    <div ng-bind-html="{{item.raw_html_content| sanitizer}}"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: This seems to give me an error of  Error: [$interpolate:interr].

Comment: This worked great! Thank you. Just a side note you have to use /embed/ or else you'll get an error of refusal to display due to it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. I was hoping to find a solution this somehow without $sce, but I guess there is no way to do so by just translating it through the html binding.